# How can you launch an object at a specific velocity and angle outside of the game engine?

Tags: physics

Lets say I have my model, Suzanne. I want to to animate Suzanne being launched from a cannon. How can I choose an exact velocity and angle to launch Suzanne? Suzanne is a rigid body.[image: suzaannenoaifnoien]

Comment: Use a [wind force field](https://youtu.be/FkrB6g3Bbgs?t=9m).

Answer (score 4):

Faceb Faceb has most of the solution.  The only bit he left out is that you also keyframe the Animated checkbox.  You have it checked at the beginning, but just before the motion of the Location keyframes are completed, you add a keyframe that turns off the Animated checkbox.

That deactivates the animation system and lets the physics system take over and it uses the velocity left over from the animation system

[image: screenshot of monkey toss]

I have keyframed Suzanne's X and Z location.  You might also keyframe Y.  Notice also the channel called `Kinematic (Rigid Body Object)` which is the fcurve for the Animated checkbox that appears green in the Physics > Rigid Body section (green or yellow means keyframed)

To know the velocity you need to know the derivative of the location.  Since I altered my keyframes to have linear interpolation it is a simple matter of `vx=dx/dt` which in this case becomes `vx=(1-0)/( (6-1) / 24fps ) = 4.8` and `vz=(3-2)/( (6-1) / 24 fps ) = 4.8` and the total velocity would be `sqrt(4.8**2 + 4.8**2) = 6.7882` .  The angle would be `atan((1-0)/(3-2)) = 45 degrees` .

If you want to choose your own velocity and angle it is probably easiest to parent Suzanne to an empty.  Rig the empty with a rotation (to choose your angle) and a starting position.  Then for Suzanne just give her a velocity on her local X axis (or maybe Y or Z depending exactly on how you orient the parent empty) by keyframing that channel of her location.  Use `x0=0` and `x1 = (frame2-frame1)/fps * velocity`  Pick `frame1` to be the first frame you want it to be in motion, and pick `frame2` such that it is after the point you want physics to to take over (which is the frame that the Animated checkbox is keyframed to become unchecked).

I used that technique to launch the cannonballs in https://youtu.be/gtP2dWmmXd8

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve this using *keyframes* and check *Animated* in the rigid body settings.

The angle and initial velocity are dependent on the two locations that are keyframed.

The angle is the angle between the two keyframed positions.

The velocity is the distance between the two keyframed positions divided by time. You know how many frames are in between en the FPS and the time can be calculated