# Throw an object with Blender

Tags: animation

I am interested to know if you can "throw objects" with Blender. Like throwing a basketball against a wall (not necessarily showing a character but showing the flow of the ball, and the interaction with the wall and floor). Or throwing a dart in the bull's eye ...

I have no idea if these kind of things can be done in Blender and what know-how and skills are required to create that kind of animations. If you can advise some tutorials that would be helpful.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69460/how-can-you-launch-an-object-at-a-specific-velocity-and-angle-outside-of-the-gam

Comment: Explore adding a "Rigid Body World" in the scene panel. Then in the "Tools" panel in the "Physics" tab you have your Rigid Body tools. Search for tutorials on "Rigid Bodies".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the physics tab in blender. Then you can enable a rigid body for both your active object(Ball) and your passive object(wall/floor). If you want to animate it follow these steps:

1. Uncheck the dynamic check box and check the animated box.
2. Insert a key frame for both of the boxes
3. Animate the motion of the ball(think about this as the ball being thrown)
4. Insert another keyframe for unchecking the animated box and checking the dynamic box.

[image]

Comment: What does it when a rigid body is animated ?

Comment: I guess I don't know exactly what dynamic vs animated means